# How to abort a fs.copyFile() in node.js

Tags: node.js

In NodeJS, how to abort a file copy in progress?

```
    const FS = require('fs') // https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

    FS.copyFile('c:/myfile.mkv', 'd:/myfile-copy.mkv', (err) => {
        if (!err) console.log('done.')
    })

    setTimeout(() => { /* abort copyFile */ }, 5000)
```

Comment: You probably can't. You can use fs.createReadStream and pipe to make a copy function of your own. then do a readstream.pause() and unpipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fs.copyFile()` is not interruptible or cancellable as it is currently written.

If you wanted that capability, you could write your own version of the copy operation that checks some cancel flag every so many bytes that it copies and, if cancelled, then cleans up the partial copy.  That wouldn't be particularly hard to implement yourself.

What is the particular use case that makes this necessary?

I can't promise this is completely bulletproof, but it works in simple testing.

```
function copyFile(src, dest) {
    let cancelFn;
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let rs = fs.createReadStream(src);
        let ws = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
        let finished = false;

        cancelFn = function cancel(err) {
            // do nothing when this function is called if we already
            // completed normally
            if (finished) return;
            cleanup();
            // when the writestream is closed, delete the file and reject the promise
            ws.once('close', function() {
                fs.unlink(dest, function() {
                    err = err || new Error("Copy cancelled");
                    reject(err);
                });
            });
            rs.pause();
            rs.unpipe(ws);
            ws.destroy();
            rs.destroy();
        }

        function cleanup() {
            rs.off('error', handleError);
            ws.off('error', handleError);
            ws.off('close', done);
        }

        function done() {
            finished = true;
            cleanup();
            resolve();
        }

        function handleError(err) {
            cancel(err);
        }

        rs.on('error', handleError);
        ws.on('error', handleError);
        ws.on('close', done);

        rs.pipe(ws);
    });

    return {
        promise: p,
        cancel: cancelFn
    }
}

// sample usage

let result = copyFile("input.txt", "output.txt");

// note, you have to be really fast to catch a copy before it finishes unless
// the file is really big or the disk is really slow
setTimeout(() => {
    result.cancel();
}, 10);

result.promise.then(result => {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("promise reject", err);
});
```

Comment: @Azevedo - I added a sample implementation for a cancellable `copyFile()` function.

Comment: This is the scenario for handling file copy from the browser, that make calls to node.js. Under some circunstances the user might want to cancel the operation.

Comment: @Azevedo - Just realize that I had to set my timer to 10ms in order to catch a 7MB file copy before it finished.  Now part of that might have been the file got cached as I tested, but unless you're talking about really large files or a slow disk, these things go can go pretty quickly.  If you're copying lots of files, you can test for cancellation between files too.

Comment: @Azevedo - Made one more change to the code in case the cancel function is called after everything has completed normally.